# Plot data points beyond the axis maximum as the maximum

Tags: excel, charts, plot, outliers, vba

I have a set of graphs that I generate automatically, that I need to adjust slightly. My Y Axis goes from 0 - 1000 but I have some values outside of this range. For those values that occur beyond 1000 I would like to plot a point at 1000 to alert the user to the fact that the data exists.

A desired features: if it would be at all possible to change the format of an individual data point based on a cell value (ie a cell value greater than 1000) that would be fantastic; this isn't necessary but it would make reviewing the data (nearly 100 charts) even easier.

thanks!

Comment: What charting framework are you using? What language? etc. You need to be a little more specific here...

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this. I am not sure the answers to those specifically, but I am creating charts in excel with a macro(it's vba so I think the language is C+++, I am really not sure?). The macro creates scatter charts. I was wondering if there is a way to display a data point at 1000 (or whatever the maximum ends up being) for any data point that exceeds the maximum. If you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: I have added the excel and vba tags for you. And I don't think vba has anything to do with C++ to be honest.

Comment: You could use formulas to split your series into two (<=1000 and >1000) and use different formatting for each set of values. I don't think you can directly plot >1000 values as =1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using macros to build your charts, do you mind using the macros to add additional columns to your data first?  You could add two additional columns, the first to have this simple code to adjust some of your data:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= IF(RC[-1]>999, 1000,RC[-1])"
....then fill down
```

Then the next column to have a simple count of data points (used later to find the point you're modifying):

```
Dim i as integer
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("Your Range")
For Each Cell In rng
i = i + 1
cell.value = i
Next
```

Now plot your graph as you would with the macro, except now you're using the Adjusted Values column.  And add this formatting macro:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim Point As String

Set rng = Range("c2:c9")
For Each Cell In rng

If Cell.Value > 999 Then
Point = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Your Chart").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Point).Select
Selection.MarkerStyle = -4105
    With Selection
    .MarkerStyle = 2
    .MarkerSize = 25
    .MarkerColor = 'Your Color (could base this off of the degree that it is above 1k)
    End With
End If
Next
```

This is strong-arming the system a bit, but it would give you what you needed.

Good luck.

-ZL

Comment: This macro caused my computer to stall indefinitely on the "Counting Lines," probably due to my lack of knowledge in implementing the solution. I was however, able to implement this general idea into a workable solution. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect on a scatter chart by adding a new data series that has the value of 1000 where the existing series exceeds 1000 and has blanks elsewhere.  This has to be done for each axis that has values that exceed the maximum you have set.

For example, here is a small data set and the additional data series that would be needed if the maximum Y value on the scatter chart was set to 10.

[image: data with new series]

When you add the new Y series to the chart, you will need to specify both the added Series Y range  and the  original Series X range. Provide a descriptive series name if you want the legend to indicate what the new data points mean,

[image: adding the new series to the chart]

Here's a (slightly) cleaned-up version of the chart with the Y-axis maximum set and a legend entry for the new data point. If the points that were exceeding the maximum were on the X-axis, you would go through a similar process.

[image: the new chart]

Comment: I think I am going to go with something like this. I was looking for something more elegant to integrate with my macro but this looks like the best solution. Thanks for the help!